# Tips on converting Embedded SQL ASP to Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server-2012

Is there a more common way on converting embedded SQL to stored procedures. I have multiple embedded selects in our ASP code and the "JOB" is to convert every embedded to stored procedures

My concern is that if I do every 114 embedded selects I will also have 114 new stored procedures. Maybe there is a simpler way of having this, an example of these 114 selects are:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE Col1 = '1'

SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1  
WHERE Col2 = '1' and Col3 = 'S'
```

They query from the same Table "Table1" but has a different where clause. Might there be a better way of doing this in 1 SP than to make 2 separates?

Comment: If my post is irrelevant here, please tell me where I could post such. Thank you.

Comment: One way would be to use an **ORM** like Entity Framework to let a tool auto-generate those trivial select queries for you - and you neither have to write inline SQL, nor create tons of stored procedures for this .... (this assumes that you mean **ASP.NET** when you mention *ASP* - not the real, classic *ASP* with VBScript...)

Comment: @marc_s unfortunately its Classic ASP. We were suppose to move to .NET but since it will take a lot more man hours for that, they decided to stick with Classic but remove embedded SQLs... im just following orders :)